# Multiple object collision as3

Tags: actionscript-3, object, hittest

I still have a little problem.
I have 6 diferent objects. Let's call them a, b, c, d, e, f. Each of these objects have containd objects (buttons), and I use them as some kind of hit zone (see picture in a link)!

http://postimg.org/image/j2h4y2c65/

Both of objects in picture are movable objects. Each of objects have start positions.
I want to do this:

If object a.hitzoneA collides with b.hitzoneB (a.hitzoneA.hitTestObject (b.hitzoneB)), return object "a" to the start position, and leave object "b" where it is.
Vice Versa, if object b.hitzoneB hits a.hitzoneA, I want object b to move to its start position.

I tryed using if/else if/else, arrays of objects, but no luck. BOTH objects go to its start positions, every time. Can someone suggest solution to this problem?

http://pastie.org/private/gfrxgzsv4jj7qdvh3vzphq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time Object A's hitbox overlaps with Object B's hitbox, the inverse is also true.  So doing a hitTest will always be true for both objects at the same time.  You can cancel the second hitTest when the first one returns true, but that will just result in object A always moving back to its start position, and never object B.

It seems like you only want the object that is moving to go back to its start position, like if the user is using the mouse to click and drag that object to another position.  If so, check for the hitTest as soon as the user tries to place it somewhere.  Then move only that object back to its start position if the hitTest returns true.

EDIT:

Here's an example onMouseReleased function (passed to your event listener):

```
private function onMouseReleased(e:Event):void{
     var movingObject:MovableObject = getMovingObject(); //returns reference to the object being moved.  Can save this reference when the user first clicks on the object to move.
     if(movingObject == a && a.hitzoneA.hitTestObject(b.hitzoneB)){
         a.x = startAx;
         a.y = startAy;
     }
     else if(movingObject == b && b.hitzoneB.hitTestObject(a.hitzoneA)){
         b.x = startBx;
         b.y = startBy;
     }
     movingObject.stopDrag();
}
```

This is still a rather clunky way to do what you want. It would scale far better using a more object-oriented approach.  However, something like this could work.

Comment: I understand. Is there a way to do this witouth hit testing it?
I though the problem was in IF/ELSE/ELSEIF loop...
Yes, just object that I'm moving.

Comment: if (a.hitzoneA.hitTestObject (b.hitzoneB)){
  a.x = startAx;
                a.y = startAy;
  }
 else if (b.hitzoneB..hitTestObject(a.hitzoneA){
                b.x = startBx;
                b.y = startBy;
                }
        else{
             a.x = startAx;
             a.y = startAy;
             b.x = startBx;
             b.y = startBy;
{

Comment: This loop is in some kind of on_release_mouse function, if you know what i mean.

Comment: That code is incorrect and would make both objects always move back if the mouse was released while they did not overlap (else clause).  I'll edit my post to show a better way to do that.

Comment: It gave me error 1046. 
I'm little pi**ed, 'couse I am new in object oriented programing, and I have to create puzzle game from scratch. I've done most of thing on my "to do in game" list, but this one...
Worst problem is that my native language is not english, and I have no expirience in Flash nor AS3...

Comment: That was only an example.  You would have to create a MovableObject class and create a getMovingObject() function for that to actually compile.  I can't create the exact solution for you unless I could see much more of the code for your project.

Comment: I'll send you via e-mail. Can you send me your e-mail?

Comment: Can you just paste the code in pastie.org and edit your first post to include a link to it?  I'd prefer to not give away my e-mail.

Comment: Ok, I put link in first post. Objects are "crveno, zeleno, plavo, ljubicasto, narandzasto, zuto". Every object have a contained object called "hitCrv, hitNar, hitPl...." (hitCrv is crveno's contained object, hitPl is for plavo, ect..)

Comment: Ok, it looks like you just need to modify your drop() function so that each if statement also checks that e.currentTarget equals crveno/plavo/etc.  For example, the first if statement would be changed to: if (e.currentTarget == crveno && crveno.hitCrv.hitTestObject(plavo.hitPl)){//code} You also need to change line 36 to e.currentTarget.stopDrag();.